# Pyes Elastic Search Refresh API Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I recently upgraded Elastic Search from v 1.7 to 2.4. I'm working in python and using pyes library to communicate to Elastic Search. In my code, I have this line in place to refresh index.

> con.indices.refresh()

This was working fine with ES 1.7, however with ES 2.4, I'm getting this exception:

> ElasticSearchException: Unknown exception type: 408

Refreshing via curl works just fine, i.e

> curl localhost:9200/_refresh

Is there any changes in Elastic Search 2.4 that is breaking this piece of code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the version of pyes library. There is a version compatibility between ES and pyes. Which is strict.

refer to the documentation here. 
http://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate/

Comment: Thanks for your answer lazywiz. I'm already using the latest version of pyes. The documentation you mentioned is to migrate to pyelasticsearch, which is a separate library I guess.